# Limit products found by visibility?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, google-shopping

I am using Magento with the following script to import our catalog into Google Shopping:

```
<?php
define('SAVE_FEED_LOCATION','google_base_feed.txt');
set_time_limit(1800);
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
try{
    $handle = fopen(SAVE_FEED_LOCATION, 'w');

    $heading = array('id','mpn', 'upc','title','description','link','image_link','price','brand','product_type','condition', 'google_product_category', 'manufacturer', 'availability');
    $feed_line=implode("\t", $heading)."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $feed_line);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prodIds=$products->getAllIds();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $counter_test = 0;

    foreach($prodIds as $productId) {

        if (++$counter_test < 30000){

            $product->load($productId);

            $product_data = array();
            $product_data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
            $product_data['mpn'] = $product->getData('upc');
            $product_data['upc'] = $product->getData('upc');

            $title_temp = $product->getName();
            if (strlen($title_temp) > 70){
                $title_temp = str_replace("Supply", "", $title_temp);
                $title_temp = str_replace("  ", " ", $title_temp);
            }
            $product_data['title'] = $title_temp;


            $product_data['description'] = substr(iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$product->getDescription()), 0, 900);
            $product_data['Deeplink'] = "http://www.domainname.co.uk/store/".$product->getUrlPath(); 
            $product_data['image_link'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();

            $price_temp = round($product->getPrice(),2);
            $product_data['price'] = round($product->getPrice(),2) * 
1.2;


            $product_data['brand'] = $product->getData('brand');

            $product_data['product_type'] = 'Pet Products and Accessories';
            $product_data['condition'] = "new";
            $product_data['category'] = $product_data['brand'];
            $product_data['manufacturer'] = $product_data['brand'];

            $product_data['availability'] = "in stock";

            foreach($product_data as $k=>$val){
                $bad=array('"',"\r\n","\n","\r","\t");
                $good=array(""," "," "," ","");
                $product_data[$k] = '"'.str_replace($bad,$good,$val).'"';
            }

            echo $counter_test  . " ";

            $feed_line = implode("\t", $product_data)."\r\n";
            fwrite($handle, $feed_line);
            fflush($handle);

        }

    }

    fclose($handle);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

the problem with this script is that it seems to import *all* products. Regardless of the fact that some of them are listed as 'Not Visible Individually'. I am trying to find a way of limiting the items listed to those that are 'Search', 'Catalog' or 'Catalog, Search'.

I notice the following line:

```
       $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

but am completely unsure on the relevance of the number 4. The script has been mashed together using a handful of different blog posts, SO answers and tutorials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way is to define a array:

```
$visibility = array(
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
);

// now you can add this filter to call your product collection

$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
```

Comment: Do you know if 'VISIBILITY_BOTH' is the correct "Magento" phrase I need?

Comment: `VISIBILITY_BOTH` means that the product is visible in search and catalog and is equal to 4, `VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG` means, that the product is just visible in catalog and is equal to 2. there a two more statuses you can use: `VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1`  and `VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH = 3 `. I think you can only use `VISIBILITY_BOTH` or `4` like mentioned below. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @danny: +1, but I'd always recommend using class constants over their values. In the end, that's what constants are for. Otherwise you need to change all places in your code using the `4` whenever Magento decides to change the values of the class constants for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing around the order that you create the collection so that the filters are last, i.e.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

Comment: Although the script still works, it still doesn't seem to be altering the scope of products. I checked, 4 = Catalog, Search.